# How to prove that $\phi'(z)<0$ for $\theta\in (0,\pi)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $a_1=(1,0), a_2$ be two points on the unit circle T of the complex place $C$. Assume that the angle between $a_1$ and $a_2$ are $\theta$. See the below graph:
[image]

Define the function
$$
r(z)=\frac{1}{z-a_1}+\frac{1}{z-a_2}
$$

Define the integral:
$$
\phi(\theta):=\int_D |r(z)|dz
$$
where $D$ is a unit disk.

I guess that $\phi(\theta)$ is decreasing on $\theta\in (0,\pi)$ and increasing on $\theta\in (\pi,2\pi)$. Moreover, $\phi'(z)=0$ as $z=\pi$. How to prove that $\phi'(z)<0$ for $\theta\in (0,\pi)$?

---

I am not sure how to compute the integral over the disk... I know how to integral it around a closed path.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451203/how-to-prove-that-phiz0-for-theta-in-0-pi without notification to either site.

Comment: The problem is completely solved on MO now (I hope).